# Automate search command in Visual Studio 2017 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, full-text-search

I need to search for a long list of phrases from a Solution. So instead of using the Ctr+Shift+F command to do it manually, is there a way to automate this search? As most I found was writing codes to search from a file, I want to use visual studio to search within its Solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DTE.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.find?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) object to set search options and invoke search. With my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension it looks like:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.Find.FindWhat = @"Test";
    DTE.Find.Target = EnvDTE.vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetSolution;

    DTE.Find.Action = EnvDTE.vsFindAction.vsFindActionFindAll;
    DTE.Find.Backwards = false;
    DTE.Find.FilesOfType = @"";
    DTE.Find.KeepModifiedDocumentsOpen = false;
    DTE.Find.MatchCase = false;
    DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = true;
    DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = false;
    DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = EnvDTE.vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral;
    DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = @"";
    DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = EnvDTE.vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResults1;
    DTE.Find.SearchSubfolders = true;
    DTE.Find.SearchPath = @"Entire Solution";
    DTE.Find.Execute();     
}
```