# Search history saver plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Can somebody recommend a search history extension for Visual Studio? What I would want is since at most time we want to search for the same thing multiple times toggling between 1 or more different searches to make changes. So is there a plugin that could save you search results to save time instead of searching every time?

TIA!

Comment: I never found a tool which matched completely my personal requirements. Hence, my orthogonal approach: Combine multiple tools and do what you need in the best matching respectively. So, you may do certain editing in Notepad++ while mainly working in VS. (My personal favorite is XEmacs but I wouldn't dare to recommend it to anybody.) All these tools have in common that they can detect if an edited file has been saved/overwritten externally and will alert you to reload. Thanks to this feature, the above approach works quite conveniently. (You ever considered to do re-factoring in AWK or Python?)

Comment: Short answer: no, nobody can recommend a search history extension for Visual Studio.  The [help/on-topic] says that **Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow**.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604664/automate-search-command-in-visual-studio-2017-c-sharp